# Find any 4 consecutive characters between two strings

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex that would detect if any combination of 4 non-whitespace characters existed between two strings. They will always be seperated by a comma. An example:

```
Labrador, Matador ---> this would match 'ador'.
Mississippi, Missing ---> This would match 'Miss' and 'issi'
Corporate, Corporation ---> This would match 'Corp' , 'orpo' , 'rpor' ,  'pora' and 'orat'
```

It's been pretty hard to find something similar to this, and the closest I've found has said this is not possible in regex. It's definitely tricky, but I wanted to make sure that it was in fact not possible before looking for a different solution.

If it is impossible, would someone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For overlapping matches it is possible with a lookahead:

```
/(?=(\S{4}).*,.*\1)/
```

Note that there is one more `issi` possible in your second line example.

Test: https://regex101.com/r/rV3gN9/2

Comment: Thanks! Good catch on the double issi. Lookaheads have been tricky for me in the past.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm happy if this helps you. Lookarounds are necessary whenever you want an overlapping match because otherwise the matched characters move the search point for the engine. Look arounds have zero width so it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
(?=([a-zA-Z]{4})[a-zA-Z]*, *[a-zA-Z]*\1)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iK3aP4/2)

Though it will find `issi` twice since `Mississippi` has 2 instanced of `issi`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html):

```
\w*([a-zA-z]{4})\w*, \w*\1\w*
```

See example: https://regex101.com/r/eW8hB7/1